# Random.Next - Am I silently creating new instances?

Tags: c#, random

`Random.Next()` randomness failures are almost always caused by creating and then using multiple instances of `System.Random` with the same seed, either with a time seed or a manual one. However, this is the only instance creation code in my class:

```
System.Random rNG;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Map.Seed))
{
    rNG = new System.Random();
}
else
{
    rNG = new System.Random(Map.Seed.GetHashCode());
}
```

Looping through this second attempt code correctly creates random numbers:

```
var resourceRoll = rNG.Next(0, this.ResourceByRoll.Count);
var resourceRow = from row in this.ProcGenResourceTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["Resource"].Equals(
        this.ResourceByRoll[resourceRoll]
    ))
```

Looping through this original attempt code often creates the same number twice in a row:

```
var resourceRow = from row in this.ProcGenResourceTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["Resource"].Equals(
        this.ResourceByRoll[rNG.Next(0, this.ResourceByRoll.Count)]
    ))
```

Am I somehow silently creating a new instance of System.Random when using a `Random.Next` call as a dictionary index? Why does my original code often return the same number twice in a row?

If it matters:

- This class is a Unity script
- I am using System.Random, not UnityEngine.Random
- My complete class is below:

---

```
using Assets.Code.Tools;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Map : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int Length { get; set; }
    public static int Width { get; set; }
    public static int ResourceChanceDenominator { get; set; }
    public static string Seed { get; set; }
    private static int[,] objectGrid;
    private DataTable ProcGenResourceTable { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<int, string> ResourceByRoll { get; set; }
    private List<GameObject> prefabTrees;
    private List<GameObject> prefabStones;


    private void Start()
    {
        this.prefabTrees = GeneralTools.GetPrefabsWithTag("Tree");
        this.prefabStones = GeneralTools.GetPrefabsWithTag("Stone");

        GenerateMap();
    }


    public void GenerateMap()
    {
        var procGenResourceTable = Resources.Load("ProcGenResourceTable") as TextAsset;
        if (procGenResourceTable != null)
        {
            this.ProcGenResourceTable = GeneralTools.GetDataTableFromCSV(procGenResourceTable, "|", true, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProcGenResourceTable could not be found");
            return;
        }

        Map.objectGrid = new int[Map.Width, Map.Length];

        this.ResourceByRoll = GetPopulatedResourceByRollDictionary();

        System.Random rNG;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Map.Seed))
        {
            rNG = new System.Random();
        }
        else
        {
            rNG = new System.Random(Map.Seed.GetHashCode());
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < Map.Length; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < Map.Width; j++)
            {
                var roll = rNG.Next(Map.ResourceChanceDenominator);

                if (roll == 1)
                {
                    // var resourceRoll = rNG.Next(0, this.ResourceByRoll.Count);
                    var resourceRow = from row in this.ProcGenResourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                                      .Where(row => row["Resource"].Equals(
                                            this.ResourceByRoll[rNG.Next(0, this.ResourceByRoll.Count)]
                                          ))
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          ModelFamily = row["Model Family"],
                                          Tags = row["Tags"]
                                      };

                    foreach (var row in resourceRow)
                    {
                        GameObject resource = null;

                        switch (row.ModelFamily)
                        {
                            case "Tree":
                                resource = Instantiate(this.prefabTrees[rNG.Next(this.prefabTrees.Count - 1)], new Vector3(i, 0, j), new Quaternion());
                                break;
                            case "Stone":
                                resource = Instantiate(this.prefabStones[rNG.Next(this.prefabStones.Count - 1)], new Vector3(i, 0, j), new Quaternion());
                                break;
                            default:
                                resource = Instantiate(this.prefabTrees[rNG.Next(this.prefabTrees.Count - 1)], new Vector3(i, 0, j), new Quaternion());
                                break;
                        }

                        var tagsListForResource = row.Tags.ToString().Split(new char[] { '|' }).ToList();
                        if (tagsListForResource.Contains("Resource"))
                        {
                            resource.tag = "Resource";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private Dictionary<int, string> GetPopulatedResourceByRollDictionary()
    {
        var resourceByRoll = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        foreach (DataRow row in this.ProcGenResourceTable.Rows)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["Weight"].ToString()))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(row["Weight"]); i++)
                {
                    resourceByRoll.Add(resourceByRoll.Count, row["Resource"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        return resourceByRoll;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the max size of your range? I don't think duplicates indicates any sort of problem. Can you give more details about what you are seeing to suggest you aren't getting random numbers? Perhaps log some of the sequences of random numbers being generated and add them to the question

Comment: @MichaelWelch I was replying to your comment when the act of typing out what I was seeing made it click how dumb I was being. Thanks for the rubberducking help. Typing an answer now.

Comment: @MichaelWelch It's not a problem with Random.Next. It's that the internal process from `.Where(row => row["Resource"].Equals(
        this.ResourceByRoll[rNG.Next(0, this.ResourceByRoll.Count)]
    ))` is re-rolling multiple times as it checks the rows and sometimes giving me multiple rows as a result. Rolling once before, saving the result to a variable, and then always checking against that variable solved the issue. I didn't realize at first that .Where() has its own looping going on.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood what was going on - this is not related to repeated random numbers.

The answer to Michael Welch's question is that I am seeing trees and rocks generate on the same coordinates.

I expected this code to only generate one row of results:

```
var resourceRow = from row in this.ProcGenResourceTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["Resource"].Equals(
        this.ResourceByRoll[rNG.Next(0, this.ResourceByRoll.Count)]
    ))
```

However, it is sometimes returns more, because `.Where()` does some looping of its own that re-rolls the number each time.

Having multiple rows returned causes the `foreach` block to generate multiple prefabs at the coordinate instead of just one.